# Converting to HTTPS

Tags: php, html, security, http, https

I have an https site and google displays the lock with the yellow triangle on top meaning:

> The site uses SSL, but Google Chrome has detected insecure content on
>   the page.  Be careful if you’re entering sensitive information on this
>   page.  Insecure content can provide a loophole for someone to change
>   the look of the page.

I want to change my site so it is completely secure and I get the green lock. However when I try to access my page through https like so `https://www.domain.com` rather than `http://www.domain.com`, most things don't work. Chrome's inspector says stuff like:

> The page at https://www.domain.com/Folder/ displayed insecure content
>   from http://website.com/media/images/photo.jpg.

Is that just because the page I'm getting my photos from is http? What are the steps I should take to start converting my entire site to https (in terms of changing code)?

Comment: It is insecure because you download non-secured content.

Comment: View source, and start identifying every location where you have a reference to ANY file as http:// instead of https:// - could be stylesheets, images, script files, etc.  Change them to be secure, and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove (or replace with `https://`) any links, images, etc from your site that link to pages via `http://`.

The warning is created because you are asking the browser to connect to (= load data from) a website that is not secured with SSL (https).

If you want to serve data that is not available via `https` from your site, your server will need to download and serve them via `https`.

Comment: when I try to access the page I get my images from using `https`, it says webpage unavailable so they probably don't have an https. Does that mean I can't use their images?

Comment: Yes, if they do not run a server with ssl enabled, you will need to remove these images.

Comment: But you can serve these images from your own site with https (see my edit)

Comment: ah i didn't even think about that for some reason, thanks I will do that.

Answer (score 7):

@Richard

As i understand from your question you may have links to external resources which are being loaded from http://... rather than https://... just identify all of these resources(i.e. images, stylesheets, javascript files and even images inside CSS) and replace protocol part "http://" with just "//". See example below:

if you have:

```
<img src="http://domain.com/path/to/image.png">
```

Replace it with:

```
<img src="//domain.com/path/to/image.png">
```

This way browser will substitute proper protocol and load resources from https:// or http:// correspondingly.

Answer (score 2):

> Is that just because the page I'm getting my photos from is http?

Yes

> What are the steps I should take to start converting my entire site to https (in terms of changing code)?

Only load resources over HTTPS.